# I want to update an array inside my JSON with onclick event| AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

here is my JSON , i want to add an element to the array inside the array product1 everytime i click a button and it should not have a limit , the value in the added field can be user defined.

```
$scope.tableContent = [
            {
                id: 1,
                sks: 'sk1',
                product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
                product2: 'prod2'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                sks: 'sk2',
                product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2', 'micro m3'],
                product2: 'prod4'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                sks: 'sk3',
                product1: 'prod5',
                product2: 'prod6'
            }];
```

add code to the javascript to make it work.

```
        $scope.addMicroM = function () {

         //some code here to add 

        };
```

here is my JSON , i want to add an element  to array of  product 1 or any other array on click of an even,similarly i want to add the same to product 2 too .

my html:

```
  <div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent">

            <div class="cell" ng-click=openModal(x)> {{x.sks}} </div>
            <div class="cell" ng-click=openModal(x)>
                <div class=cellD ng-repeat=" pika in x.product1">{{pika}}</div>
            <div class="cellD" ng-click="addMicroM()">+</div>


    </div>
    <div class="cell" ng-click=openModal(x)>{{x.product2}}</div>
    <div class="cell" ng-click="addCol($event)">+</div>


</div>
<div class="row">

    <div class=cell ng-click=addRow()>+</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying that isn't working out for you?

Comment: Please correct your phrase friend, it's not clear!

Comment: yeah @GiovaniVercauteren its not working , and let me edit it , again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.addMicroM = function(obj, microm) {
    $scope.tableContent.forEach(function(elem){
         if(elem.id == obj.id){
             elem.product1.push(microm);
             if(elem.product2.constructor === Array){
                 elem.product2.push(microm);
             } else{
                var tmpArr = [];
                tmpArr.push(elem.product2);
                tmpArr.push(microm);
                elem.product2 = tmpArr;
             }
         }
    });
}
```

And in your html:

```
<div class="cellD" ng-click="addMicroM(x, 'micro m3')">+</div>
```